# Identify an ALPS potentiometer

Tags: identification, potentiometer

This potentiometer reads between 0 and 115K as I rotate the shaft. The wedged part of the shaft is 10mm.

Can anyone identify the part number?

[image: back]
[image: top]

Answer (score 2):

That's an Alps Alpine **RK09L/RK09L1220A1B** 9mm Dual Unit Metal shaft snap-in type Potentiometer, get more info [here](https://tech.alpsalpine.com/prod/e/html/potentiometer/rotarypotentiometers/rk09l/rk09l_list.html). Also here's the product [Datasheet](https://tech.alpsalpine.com/prod/e/pdf/potentiometer/rotarypotentiometers/rk09l/rk09l.pdf) for you, cheers :)